# react-calendar add graphical content to day cell

Tags: css, reactjs, react-tsx

I would like to add some icons or text to day cell of react-calendar.
In more detail: I receive a schedule from the server (for example, a list of birthdays) in json format. Аnd according to this schedule i want to add various icons or symbols to the calendar (like in the pictures below).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1syH.png)

im new at this domain of cs, can you please guide me how to approach to the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.